# C++ ORB Feature Matching with FLANN Lsh Error

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to match Orb features using FLANN matcher and LSH, and it gives me this error:

OpenCV: terminate handler is called! The last OpenCV error is:

> OpenCV(4.1.0) Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats (> type=5 > ) in buildIndex_, file
>   C:\opencv\source\opencv-4.1.0\modules\flann\src\miniflann.cpp, line
>   315

What is the reason for this?

Descriptors are already converted to CV_32F.

```cpp
cv::FlannBasedMatcher matcher = cv::FlannBasedMatcher(cv::makePtr<cv::flann::LshIndexParams>(12, 20, 2));

std::vector< std::vector<cv::DMatch> > matches;

matcher.knnMatch(descriptors1, descriptors2, matches, 2 );
```

Comment: What did you discover when you stepped through your code, line by line, in your debugger (while inspecting control flow and variable values)?

Comment: I can't run a debugger right now. Some error with libraries. I will add a result when I fix this error, if first problem is not solved till then.

Comment: The problem was solved. The problem was that descriptors should not be converted to CV_32F and that I need to check if (matches[i].size() >= 2). Thanks!